# Mysql database browsers not working after upgrade

Tags: 14.04, server, package-management, dpkg, mysql

I needed version 5.7 of mysql server for a project. I upgraded from version 5.5 to 5.7 using [this tutorial](http://www.devopsservice.com/installation-of-mysql-server-5-7-on-ubuntu-14-04/). The upgrade was successful and I am able to use the updated version via command line. However, mysql browsers (mysql-workbench as sqlyog as well as phpmyadmin) stopped working after the upgrade.

Workbench says :

```
    Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist
```

I can log-in using PHPMyAdmin but unable to select any database. It says

```
SELECT * FROM data_dictionary.CHARACTER_SETS
MySQL said: Documentation
#1146 - Table 'data_dictionary.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist
```

During the upgrade the following message appeared.

```
dpkg: mysql-client-5.5: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 mysql-workbench depends on mysql-client; however:
  Package mysql-client is not configured yet.
  Package mysql-client-5.5 which provides mysql-client is to be removed.
```

which made me think it is because no mysql client is available now. Please advise me how to fix this and get my mysql client up and running.

I am unable to install libmysqlclient, tried reinstalling phpmyadmin with no luck.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bits) MySQL version after upgrade :

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.8-rc, for Linux (i686) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Thanks

Complete upgrade logs :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-community-server' instead of 'mysql-server-5.7'
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-server
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 mysql-client mysql-community-client mysql-community-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-common mysql-server
2 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 4 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
Need to get 24.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 107 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-server i386 5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04 [12.0 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libmecab2 i386 0.996-1.1 [237 kB]
Get:3 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-common i386 5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04 [548 kB]
Get:4 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-client i386 5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04 [12.0 kB]
Get:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-community-client i386 5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04 [7,591 kB]
Get:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mysql-5.7-dmr mysql-community-server i386 5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04 [16.1 MB]
Fetched 24.5 MB in 10min 46s (37.9 kB/s)                                       
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 1363890 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) over (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
(Reading database ... 1363890 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
mysql stop/waiting
Removing mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
(Reading database ... 1363728 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) over (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client_5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
dpkg: mysql-client-5.5: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 mysql-workbench depends on mysql-client; however:
  Package mysql-client is not configured yet.
  Package mysql-client-5.5 which provides mysql-client is to be removed.

(Reading database ... 1363817 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Removing mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client.
(Reading database ... 1363762 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-community-client_5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2.
Preparing to unpack .../libmecab2_0.996-1.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2 (0.996-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-community-server_5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04_i386.deb ...
.
Unpacking mysql-community-server (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf ...
Setting up mysql-community-client (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Setting up mysql-client (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Setting up libmecab2 (0.996-1.1) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/mysql ...
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
.....
 * MySQL Community Server 5.7.8-rc is started
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am currently wrestling with.  Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @WillemvanGerven, 
Try using,  
    sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force --upgrade-system-tables
  
However, database clients like, mysql workbench and navicat will not display the JSON type columns. You have to execute your sqls in phpmyadmin or in terminal to see the results.
Then restart mysql server  
    sudo service mysqld restart